# Call custom converter after default in dozer

Tags: java, dozer

Does **Dozer** could call custom converter after default?
I want to create something like chain. At first I want to call default converter to make most of convertion work and only after that call custom converter to populate complex fields?

**EDIT**

by default when I create custom converter I need to override two methods. Each of this method has 2 arguments `source object` and `target object`. But when we call `convertTo` method second argument(`target object`) equals to null. So may be I need to specify something in mapping file to make dozer process default converter before custom?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After look into source code I understand that this probably imposible. Instead of this dozer library propose using custom-converters at field level like this:

```
<mapping wildcard="false" >
        <class-a>package.A</class-a>
        <class-b>package.B</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>id</a>
            <b>id</b>
        </field>
        <field custom-converter="test.AtoBNameFieldCustomConverter">
            <a>name</a>
            <b>name</b>
        </field>
</mapping>
```

May be this help someone.